# Magento 1.10 Enterprise Salesrule Product Subselection Error

Tags: php, magento

So I am trying to get up a fixed amount sales rule in Magneto. When I login to admin I go to Promotions --> Shopping Cart Price Rules and create a new rule. When I go to the Conditions tab (From the left menu) I start to create my sale rule condition. When I try to select "Product subselection" from the dropdown menu in the conditions tag. It return and foreach php warning -->

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in
>   /var/www/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Condition/Abstract.php
>   on line 246

I've also notice that some of the rules that I've ported over to this magento instance has the same error. But seems to only happen when "Product subselection" is set from the port-over or when I try to create one from scratch.

This link describes similar issue I am having (Sorry it's partly in Russian) http://magento-forum.ru/topic/851/

I've also read that this was a core issue back in 1.5. But was fixed http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=11214 (May need to login to Magento to view this issue)

I verified that the code has been updated in app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Condition/Abstract.php on line 246

Can anyone provide me with additional information on how I can go about fixing this bug. I have checked multiple instance of Magento Enterprise 1.10 with the same data set and all have this same bug. Thanks in advance and let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Since Magento Enterprise Edition 1.10 is based on community edition 1.5, it makes sense to a patch from Magento core team to fix that particular bug. And you will be safe to modify core in this case, since you are applying core code.

The issue was fixed in CE 1.6.0.0. According to the following blame it was fixed by modifying method called `getValueSelectOptions()`

https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blame/magento-1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Condition/Abstract.php#L246

So you just need:

1. Open app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Condition/Abstract.php
2. Locate getValueSelectOptions() method
3. Replace its contents with the following code from changes made by code team:

   ```
       public function getValueSelectOptions()
       {
           $valueOption = $opt = array();
           if ($this->hasValueOption()) {
              $valueOption = (array) $this->getValueOption();
           }
           foreach ($valueOption as $k => $v) {
              $opt[] = array('value' => $k, 'label' => $v);
           }
           return $opt;
       }
   ```
4. Save file and ensure that the issue is fixed.